# How to check dispatch_async get called or not earlier for same operation

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, dispatch-async

I faced a problem. My application downloading images from server and showing in a `UITableView` For downloading the images I am using `dispatch_async`.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // downloading image from server
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // update UI for showing downloaded image
    });
});
```

Now the problem is if user scroll up and down very fast then multiple `dispatch_async` get fired for the same image. I have image id. Is there any way to check whether a `dispatch_async` get fired or not for that image or not by image id?

Comment: I recommend making use of open source code to handle typical operations such as this. I've used SDWebImage https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: I want to do it from myself.

Comment: First of all: just use `NSURLSession`. If you're manually doing a blocking background call for some reason, you're throwing away battery life and app performance.

Comment: This comment is not relate to this question or the posted answer. I am just want to share that the question we posted in `stack overflow`  is copied by other site. Here is the clone of my question. http://beauty98star.blogspot.in/2015/03/how-to-check-dispatchasync-get-called.html

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to set up your own mechanism for keeping track of whether there were any pending requests for that image (e.g. a dictionary keyed by the image URL absolute string or something like that). The thing is, it's not as simple as that, as the cell that now needs to be updated may be different than (or in addition to) the cell for which it was originally requested. This gets ugly quickly.

But I'd step back and ask whether this is the root problem, or a symptom of a broader problem. For example, if the user scrolls down relatively quickly to the 100th row. Is that image request backlogged behind the previous 99 rows? When you're in that sort of situation, the problem you describe starts to become serious, because if you now scroll quickly back up to the top before the other 99 images have finished downloading, you'll be issuing requests to get them *again.*

But, if you change your asynchronous image retrieval to cancel requests for cells that are not visible, suddenly this serious problem becomes somewhat academic. Plus, you have the added benefit that the image for the 100th row that the user rapidly scrolled to is not backlogged behind all of the other image requests, so it appears quite quickly.

This means that you want to employ cancelable asynchronous requests. This would therefore suggest using `NSURLSession` (or delegate-based `NSURLConnection` if you have to support OS versions that predate `NSURLSession`). Also, this would generally make one lean towards operation queues and subclassed asynchronous `NSOperation` subclass rather than GCD queue suggested by your question (to make them cancelable, asynchronous, and also to constrain the degree of concurrency). And then you have to then implement the code that makes use of all of this cancellation logic that you've so industriously created (e.g. `UIImageView` category or some image request manager that your `UITableViewDataSource` and/or `UITableViewCell` subclass uses).

Also, you want to make sure that you employ a cache mechanism (possibly both to memory and persistent storage). This way, if you've already retrieved a particular image, when you scroll back to that row, the image is ready for you to retrieve it, not requiring another network call.

I know that you have said that you want to do this yourself, but this is a non-trivial amount of work to do properly. This is why I (and others) suggest you consider checking out one of the `UIImageView` categories that allow you to asynchronously retrieve an image. See the `UIImageView` categories provided by [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). If you're properly dequeuing cells, these achieve very responsive UI while retrieving the images asynchronously. They effectively cancel requests for cells that are reused, thereby prioritizing visible cells. They also cache results resulting in good performance as you scroll back.

Answer (score 0):

For that you should store in some place the downloaded images or mark if there is a current operation for them. So you will be doing basically a image cache mechanism. I will advise that instead to do that you can use a well tested library for that like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) that precisely deal with download images and cached them to memory or disk.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple: use `NSURLSession` rather than rolling your own attempt at asynchronous URL fetches. Rely on its caching to avoid repeat downloads where the previous download completed. Then all you have to worry about is repeat requests for downloads that are currently ongoing.

The easiest thing is probably just to keep two dictionaries: URL to `NSURLSessionDataTask` and URL to array of completion handlers.

When a cell wants a URL it calls into the handler for those two dictionaries, supplying a completion handler.

If there's no data task for that URL, the handler creates one and starts it, also creating a dictionary containing just that completion handler. Both are put into their respective dictionaries.

If there is a data task for that URL, the completion handler is added to the array in the second dictionary.

Tasks are created with a completion block that calls the handler, which upon receipt will remove the task from the first dictionary and call everything in the array in the second dictionary, then removing the array from there.

Given that you're view related, the handler permits external calls from the main queue only. It will ensure that the work subsequent to a completed data task is also performed on the main queue. That means you'll have no concurrency issues.